# Java: Coordinate Transformation - Rotation & Scale

Tags: java, android, matrix, coordinates, trigonometry

Given is a rotated rectangle which is inscribed into another rectangle.
Both rectangles have their own coordinate systems.
In the inscribed & rotated rectangle there is a point **P** with the coordinates relative to this rectangle (red).
Wanted are the coordinates of this points relative to the outer rectangle (green):
**EDIT:** Given are also the width and height of both rectangles + the angle of the rotation

Image of an overview: [image: http://i.imgur.com/QH96n7x.png]

My attempts with a transform matrix (setRotate() & setScale()) failed and with Trigonometry I neither got it working.

How can I calculate the position of point **P** relative to the outer rectangle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you must convert coordinates in one system.

Comment: This is also where I failed. I am seeking for (code-) advice on how to approach such a conversion.

Comment: (1) Are you given the rotation of the red rectangle or are you expected to detect that? (2) Is this a homework problem? StackOverflow is often reluctant to outright solve a student's work for them but will give direction and tips.

Comment: I find this post. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32555/how-do-i-convert-between-two-different-2d-coordinate-systems 
I don't know if it is right but you can try

Comment: @TheCapn (1) Edited main post (2) It's for a private Android project where I need this to calculate the drag offset for a rotated ImageView while draging (where the outer rectangle is the draw canvas and the point P is the touch location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2:** A friend of mine pointed out a much more elegant solution (Thanks!). Here it is:

```
@Override
public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
{
    shadowSize.set((int) width + 1, (int) height + 1);

    float x = offsetX - w / 2, y = offsetY - h / 2;
    shadowTouchPoint.x = Math.round(x * c - y * s * sFac + w / 2 + (width - w) / 2);
    shadowTouchPoint.y = Math.round(x * s * sFac + y * c + h / 2 + (height - h) / 2);
}
```

*sFac* is defined as:

```
float sFac = (float) Math.signum(rotationRad);
```

---

Alright, I managed to solve it with Trigonometry.
For anyone interested, here is the source code for my custom DragShadowBuilder which is used in Android to drag and drop *rotated* and *scaled* View objects:

```
public class TargetDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder
{
    ImageView view;
    float offsetX, offsetY;

    double rotationRad;
    float w;
    float h;
    double s;
    double c;
    float width;
    float height;

    public TargetDragShadowBuilder(final ImageView view, float offsetX, float offsetY)
    {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
        this.offsetX = offsetX * view.getScaleX();
        this.offsetY = (int) (offsetY * view.getScaleY());

        rotationRad = Math.toRadians(view.getRotation());
        w = view.getWidth() * view.getScaleX();
        h = (int) (view.getHeight() * view.getScaleY());
        s = Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad));
        c = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad));
        width = (int) (w * c + h * s);
        height = (int) (w * s + h * c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.scale(view.getScaleX(), view.getScaleY(), width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.rotate(view.getRotation(), width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.translate((width - view.getWidth()) / 2, (height - view.getHeight()) / 2);

        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
    {
        shadowSize.set((int) width + 1, (int) height + 1);

        double x = offsetX, y = offsetY;
        if(rotationRad < 0)
        {
            final double xC = offsetX / c;
            x = xC + s * (offsetY - xC * s);
            final double yC = offsetY / c;
            y = yC + s * (w - offsetX - yC * s);
        }
        else if(rotationRad > 0)
        {
            final double xC = offsetX / c;
            x = xC + s * (h - offsetY - xC * s);
            final double yC = offsetY / c;
            y = yC + s * (offsetX - yC * s);
        }

        shadowTouchPoint.x = (int) Math.round(x);
        shadowTouchPoint.y = (int) Math.round(y);
    }
}
```

It is valid for rotations from **-90° to +90°**.
If anyone has a cleaner or easier solution I am still interested in it.

**EDIT:** And here is the code for how I handle the drop of the View object.

```
private class TargetDragListener implements OnDragListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e)
    {
        switch(e.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                if(e.getLocalState() instanceof TargetItem)
                {
                    TargetItem target = (TargetItem) e.getLocalState();
                    dropTarget(target, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                ((DragableItem) e.getLocalState()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private void dropTarget(TargetItem target, float x, float y)
{
    target.setDragged(false);
    target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    target.bringToFront();

    final float scaleX = target.getScaleX(), scaleY = target.getScaleY();
    double rotationRad = Math.toRadians(target.getRotation());
    final float w = target.getWidth() * scaleX;
    final float h = target.getHeight() * scaleY;
    float s = (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad));
    float c = (float) Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad));
    float sFac = (float) -Math.signum(rotationRad);

    target.offsetX *= scaleX;
    target.offsetY *= scaleY;

    x += -target.offsetX * c - target.offsetY * s * sFac;
    y += target.offsetX * s * sFac - target.offsetY * c;
    float[] pts = { x, y };
    float centerX = x + c * w / 2f + sFac * s * h / 2f;
    float centerY = y - sFac * s * w / 2f + c * h / 2f;

    transform.setRotate(-target.getRotation(), centerX, centerY);
    transform.mapPoints(pts);

    target.setX(pts[0] + (w - target.getWidth()) / 2);
    target.setY(pts[1] + (h - target.getHeight()) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of an overkill, but [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) (Java Topology Suite) provides tons of useful functions for dealing with 2D coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is indeed too heavy for my application since I could solve everything else with Trigonometry.